# Social sprites doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I can't use this social sprite no matter how many values i try .
The picture is 700 x 400 pixels

Html looks like

```css
.social a {
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-indent: 20000px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url(https://i.gyazo.com/f24952f2c3460c6851a108b4f98cee68.jpg)
}

#facebook {
  background-position:
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <a href="http://instagram.com/anotoriousgummy" target="_blank" id="instagram"> Instagram </a>
  <a href="http://facebook.com/GummyGod" target="_blank" id="facebook"> Facebook </a>
```

image:  `https://i.gyazo.com/f24952f2c3460c6851a108b4f98cee68.jpg`

Comment: `background-positon:` is misspelled and is missing its value.

Comment: Have you tried defined a `background-size` property?

Comment: I tried all values ,i just left it like that when i got mad for you to see guys

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem... what is really going on?

Comment: @GummyGod Well its still mispelled and you should put in some values you tried so people can see if your syntax is wrong or something.

Comment: @zgood i tried -100px 0px; 100px 0px; etc etc but i can't get it to work,i attached the image in the post maybe someone can tell me the correct values,i got it to work but i just can't properly make it display the correct image

Comment: This [online tool](http://www.spritecow.com/) can help you. It can generate the correct css for your sprite.

Comment: @zgood thanks a lot,it didn't work with my sprite but with another. i'm just starting so i need to do a website for my final exam in html and css all fine except those sprites so yea,thanks a lot!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/waLx9a2h/

Answer (score 0):

You were using 700 x 400 pixel picture, which was very big as compared to the 32 x 32 pixel anchor tag in which you wanted to fit the social icon in. So, you are required to edit the background size of the 700 x 400 pixel image.

After that, you can find the background position of the icon you are looking for.

I have made small changes in your fiddle for it to work as per your use case.

My code snippet is as follows:

```css
.social {
  
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
}

.social a {
  transition: 0.5s;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: block;
  text-indent: 20000px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: 250px;
  background-image: url(https://i.gyazo.com/f24952f2c3460c6851a108b4f98cee68.jpg)
}

#facebook{
  
  background-position: -1px 107px;
}

#instagram{
  
  background-position: 145px 107px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social">
  <a href="http://instagram.com/anotoriousgummy" target="_blank" id="instagram"> Instagram </a>
  <a href="http://facebook.com/GummyGod" target="_blank" id="facebook"> Facebook </a>
</div>
```